# Changing style.backgroundImage to php $_SESSION

Tags: javascript, php

In my .php I have `session_start();`, and a default avatar for specific users `$_SESSION['avatar']`. These avatars is displayed with `background-image:`. I made a JavaScript that changes the `background-image` to the one uploaded `input`, but before the user choose to `Save` this image as their new profile avatar, they have the option to `Cancel` what they are doing. If they do `Cancel` I want to change the background back to their avatar, and I was thinking this would work, but it doesn't:

**.php**

```php
session_start();
$CurrentAvatar = $_SESSION['avatar'];
```

**.html**

```html
<div id="avatar"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="imgDivEdit"></div>
        <div id="ChangeImg" class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Change Image</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                           
    <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="imageUpload" placeholder="Photo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" required="" capture>
    <div id="Change" hidden>
        <input  type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-info Save"/> <input type="button" onclick="Cancel()" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-info Cancel"/> <p style="font-size:11px;">Max size: 1Mb</p>
    </div>
</form>

<style>
#imgDivEdit{
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-image: url("data:image/jpeg;base64,'.$_SESSION['avatar'].'");
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

**.js**

```js
$("#imageUpload").change(function() {
   $("#Change").show();
});
function Cancel() {
   var CurrentAvatar = "<?php echo $CurrentAvatar;?>";
   $("#Change").hide();
   document.getElementById("imgDivEdit").style.backgroundImage = 
   "url(data:image/jpeg;base64,CurrentAvatar)";
 }
$("#ChangeImg").click(function(e) {
   $("#imageUpload").click();
 });

function fasterPreview(uploader) {
    if (uploader.files && uploader.files[0]) {
       var reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(uploader.files[0]);
    reader.onloadend = function(){
       document.getElementById("imgDivEdit").style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";  
 }
}
 }
 $("#imageUpload").change(function() {
   fasterPreview(this);
});
```

Comment: Is `$_SESSION['avatar']` an url or a base64-encoded image?

Comment: This: `"url(data:image/jpeg;base64,CurrentAvatar)"` will not insert the value of `CurrentAvatar`. And if you want php tags to work inside HTML files, you have to rename them to end in `.php`.

Comment: its a base64-encoded image from my sql server, but when i define the `$_SESSION['avatar']` i use `base64_encode()`, so thats good enough. If i use `<img>` i can show the avatar. So basically the session is `base64_encode($avatar)`.

Comment: It's all `.php` files, my bad, i just copyed things from my file, and showed what was html and php and .js, @ChrisG

Comment: Ok, I see. My advice would be to completely separate PHP and JS logic as far as possible. Break this apart into two unrelated problems: 1. transfer the session avatar URL to the client 2. JS logic which changes the background image. Problem 1 is easy: Add `<script>const avatarURL = "url(data:image/jpeg;base64,<?= $_SESSION['avatar'] ?>)";</script>` to your php file. WIth PHP concerns out of the way, you can focus on problem 2.

Comment: i just had to set the `background-image` to `document.getElementById("imgDivEdit").style.backgroundImage ="";`, well at least it was simple haha, thought i had to set it to the old avatar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overcomplicated with too many functions. Keep it simple. Click **Run code snippet** bellow bellow.

I rewrote my initial answer, therefore the code bellow is using pure JS and no jQuery.

```js
document.getElementById('imageUpload').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        
    let preview_div = document.getElementById("imgDivEdit"),
        change_div  = document.getElementById("Change");
    
        
  // If there are files, preview them, else go back to initial background
  // which is defined inside <style> tags
    if (this.files && this.files[0]) {
       
       change_div.style.display = 'block';
         
       let reader = new FileReader();
       reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
       reader.onloadend = function(){
          preview_div.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + reader.result + ")";  
       }
    } else {
       Cancel();
    }
});

function Cancel(){

   let preview_div = document.getElementById("imgDivEdit"),
       change_div  = document.getElementById("Change");
        
   change_div.style.display = 'none';
   preview_div.style.backgroundImage = '';
}
```

```html
<div id="avatar">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="imgDivEdit"></div>
        <div id="ChangeImg" class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Change Image</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">                           
    <input id="imageUpload" type="file" name="imageUpload" placeholder="Photo" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" required="" capture>
    <div id="Change" hidden>
        <input  type="submit" name="Save" id="Save" value="Save" class="btn btn-info Save"/> <input type="button" onclick="Cancel()" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-info Cancel"/> <p style="font-size:11px;">Max size: 1Mb</p>
    </div>
</form>

<style>
#imgDivEdit{
    width: 125px;
    height: 125px;
    background-image: url(data:image/jpeg;base64,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);
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it was almost right! delete the else statement, and just have `onclick="Cancel()"`. This worked like a charm! Thanks!!

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I added an even simpler solution.

Comment: How did you write my `form` then? Can't really get the more simple version, to work for me.

Comment: Added an edit to your answer, and that worked for me.

Comment: Thanks! It works for me, i had to change it a little, but it works ;)